# OnDelete in EntityTypeBuilder<T> ASP.NET Core 2 Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I use the following modelbuilder to setup my relationships on my database.

In my datacontext I have;

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(schema: DbGlobals.SchemaName);

    modelBuilder.AddConfiguration<Address>(new AddressConfiguration());
    /*reduced for brevity*/

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

where in the `AddressConfiguration()` i have the following;

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

namespace Data.EF.Configuration
{
    internal class AddressConfiguration : DbEntityConfiguration<Address>
    {
        public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Address> entity)
        {
            entity.HasKey(x => x.Id);
            entity.Property(x => x.Latitude).HasColumnType($"decimal(9,6)").IsRequired();
            entity.Property(x => x.Longitude).HasColumnType($"decimal(9,6)").IsRequired();
            //I have tried the following but it says doesnt exist
            //entity.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        }
    }
}
```

Now my address model has a `List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }`. How can I configure the model. to delete cascade on when the Address is deleted?

I found the following link;

[Delete Cascade in EF Core](http://mrshipley.com/2016/04/24/enabling-cascade-delete-in-ef-core-using-the-fluent-api-code-first/)

Which is detailing an `OnDelete` method, however this doesnt seem to be present on the `EntityTypeBuilder<T>`?

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here please?

Comment: yes, when It tried to remove an item it throws an error due to the FK references.

Comment: Did you try `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)`?

Comment: @viveknuna yes I get a `does not contain a defination for OnDelete` error i'll update the question to contain my using statements

Comment: It's in `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`

Comment: Yes I have that reference, but that just brings in `DeleteBehaviour.Cascade` into scope, not `OnDelete`

Comment: Cascade delete is a **relationship** behavior, not entity. Hence `OnDelete` is available only on relationship configuration fluent API, as shown in the link btw. And there is no need to seek external sources, the EF Core documentation is the first place to start with. In your case, [Relationships - Cascade Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#cascade-delete-1)

Comment: `OnDelete`  is available on `ReferenceCollectionBuilder` object. You should define the relationship as `entity.HasMany(a => a.Contacts).WithOne(c => c.Address).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`OnDelete` specifies how to configure delete operation when applied to delete the dependent entities in the relationship when the principal is deleted or the relationship is severed.

It is available on `ReferenceCollectionBuilder`|`ReferenceReferenceBuilder` objects. Read about [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.referencecollectionbuilder?view=efcore-2.0).

**Solution**

You should define the relationship as

```
    entity
        .HasMany(a => a.Contacts)
        .WithOne(c => c.Address)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```